# MySQL query NOT something

Tags: mysql, wordpress

This is the MySQL query I am running:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM wp_social_stuff_events 
    WHERE `user_1_id` = 63 
        OR `user_1_id` = 143 
        OR `user_2_id` = 63 
        OR `user_2_id` = 143 
    ORDER BY `event_timestamp` DESC LIMIT 100
```

How would I use that query but say I don't want any results where "user_1_id" is 53? I tried using `AND user_1_id NOT 53` at the end but I can't seem to get that to work either (not sure if it is the correct way)?

Any ideas?

Comment: The MySQL not equals operator has two forms, which you can use interchangably:  `!=` and `<>` both mean "not equals".  They are the opposite of using `=`.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_social_stuff_events 
WHERE (`user_1_id` = 63 
OR `user_1_id` = 143 
OR `user_2_id` = 63 
OR `user_2_id` = 143)
AND user_1_id <> 53
ORDER BY `event_timestamp` DESC LIMIT 100
```

You can use != or <> for not equal as you can read in the [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html). It's also require to have parentheses because AND is executed before OR. See [MySql Operator Precedent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html).

Comment: Would it make sense to put the single <> check first to short circut the logic?  The one condition can make it fail, preventing a check on up to 4 others.  It's a tiny improvement, I realize.

Answer (score 3):

```
AND user_1_id <> 53
```

would work as well (different than).

Comment: So would I add that before the ORDER BY and after the last OR?

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
`user_1_id` <> 53
```

<> is the not equal operator in MySQL

See here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM wp_social_stuff_events 
    WHERE `user_1_id` = 63 
        OR `user_1_id` = 143 
        OR ((`user_2_id` = 63 OR `user_2_id` = 143) 
         AND `user_1_id` <> 53) 
    ORDER BY `event_timestamp` DESC LIMIT 100
```